# How do I display a whole category from a text file?

Tags: java

I managed to display 1 record of the asked category but what i need is for the program to display everything from that category. If it's too vague the code might help. Thanks in advance

```
public static void SearchCatRecord() throws Exception
{
    LoadFile();

    System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t---------SEARCH CATEGORIZED ITEM--------");
    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t*******************************");
    System.out.print("\t\t\tEnter Category: ");
    String searchnum = br.readLine();

    boolean found = false;
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            String record[] = list.get(i).split(",");
            String num = record[1];
            if(searchnum.equals(num))
            {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\t---------RECORD FOUND----------");
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\tProduct Number      : "+record[0]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tCategory              : "+record[1]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tProduct Name          : "+record[2]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tPrice                 : "+record[3]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tQuantity              : "+record[4]);
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\t*******************************");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                found = true;
                System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\tSearch Completed");   
                exiting();


            }

        }
        if(found == false)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\tNo Record Found");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
            exiting();
        }
        MainMenu();
}
```

The following code asks the user which category should the program display. then it displays the asked category but it only displays one record.

Comment: Could you show your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you call `exiting();` when you found the first record. You should remove it in your loop.

for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    String record[] = list.get(i).split(",");
    String num = record[1];
    if(searchnum.equals(num))
    {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\t---------RECORD FOUND----------");
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\tProduct Number      : "+record[0]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tCategory              : "+record[1]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tProduct Name          : "+record[2]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tPrice                 : "+record[3]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tQuantity              : "+record[4]);
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\t*******************************");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}

System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\tSearch Completed");
if(found == false)
{
        System.out.println("\t\t\tNo Record Found");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
}
exiting();
```

Comment: Wow I didnt realize it was that simple... but I still need a way for the program to ask the user if he/she wants to go back to the main menu  or exit.. which was actually the "exiting()" method

any suggestions how I can work around it?

Comment: @MonDavid you can just add this after all records are printed. see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the records then you should not breakout after finding one record that meets your criteria. I believe your method invocation `exiting()` is not needed in loop.

On a side note why are you setting `found=true` twice in the loop? Also what is the need of `Thread.sleep(2000)` in the code?